# Invisible .htaccess Redirect from /public_html/ to /public_html/folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to point the root domain of my hosting account to a subdirectory (joomla).  I want this to be invisible (i.e. browser address bar doesn't change).  Also, I need this to work when a user hits the root or a subfile/subfolder.

I've tried the following rules, which work individually, but I can't get them to work together.

This one works when no subfile/subfolder is specified:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /joomla/ [L]
```

And this one works when a subfile/subfolder IS specified:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)$ /joomla/$1 [L]
```

I just can't figure out how to combine them.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1 [L]
```

Should work (untested). The key difference between this and your second attempt is the + vs *. The + will match one or more, whereas the * will match 0 or more, so this should work also when no file/subdirectory is specified.

Comment: That one throws a 500 server error with or without file/folder.  When I add "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" it works with the file/folder specified, but throws a 500 error without.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1 [L]
```

`.*` will also match an empty string. You also more than likely want to do the `-d` check to make sure that they aren't accessing a directory that exists (though, thinking about it, this might mess with the `/` matching, I don't know).

Comment: Works for the file/folder, but the root never redirects. Just gives me a directory listing.  Without the -d line it throws a 500 error when hitting the root.